# What objects will be passed to a custom ArgumentMatcher in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am creating a custom argument matcher in mockito.  Using [this](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) example:

```
class IsListOfTwoElements extends ArgumentMatcher<List> {
    public boolean matches(Object list) {
        return ((List) list).size() == 2;
    }
}
```

This made me wonder why the type of the parameter `list` is `Object` instead of `List`. 
Can the argument passed to the match function be something else? And if so shouldn't the example check the type of the parameter and return `false` if it isn't a `List`?

To rephrase the question a little: 
Does mockito promise to only pas the correct type to the `matches` function? If so, why doesn't it use the generic type. And if not why doesn't the example return false if the wrong type is passed to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the mockito matchers use Hamcrest matchers, in the javadoc link you provided, you'll see that it inherits the signature of `matches` in interface `org.hamcrest.Matcher` which appear to not be generic in the actual interface.

If the compiler has made his job correctly you can assume you'll get the correct type though.

Note that the `ArgumentCaptor` approach is now recommanded for complex assertions, where you can use AssertJ (maintained clone of FEST-Assert) for example.

Answer (score 3):

- If you extend [`ArgumentMatcher`](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html), you will receive an object, and it's your responsibility to cast it. Mockito will describe it based on the class name.
- If you extend [`BaseMatcher`](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/BaseMatcher.java), you will receive an object, and it's your responsibility to cast it. The description will only say what the matcher was passed, not what it was expecting.
- If you use [`TypeSafeMatcher`](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher.java), you will receive an object of your chosen type, and it's your responsibility to describe it. It will check non-nullity and class type for you, and provide a sane error message if the class doesn't match.

Don't worry about making a bad cast in your matcher. Mockito wraps calls to its verification within a very generous try/catch block in both [verification](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/source/browse/src/org/mockito/internal/verification/argumentmatching/ArgumentMatchingTool.java#43) and [invocation matching](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/source/browse/src/org/mockito/internal/invocation/InvocationMatcher.java#67) so a ClassCastException will return false (or fail to match) anyway.

---

Why, then, would interface [`Matcher`](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/Matcher.java) accept more than its type parameter lets on?

> This method matches against Object, instead of the generic type T. This is because the caller of the Matcher does not know at runtime what the type is (because of type erasure with Java generics). It is down to the implementations to check the correct type.

So, in other words, even if Matcher were to be parameterized it wouldn't provide a very strong type safety check at runtime. However, in Mockito, it's very useful--`argThat(Matcher<T>)` returns a value of type `T` instead of `Object`, so you don't have to cast every single use of `argThat(...)` in your tests.